# Get HTML of div element returned by .get with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I'm trying to get the HTML of a specific div returned by a .get request (the .get request, returns HTML data with 3 divs with 3 different ids)

Here's my code:

```
$.get("ajax/learn-more.html", function(data){
    var $response = $(data);
    alert($response.find('#main-images')); // <= prints [Object object]
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data); // <= displaysthe whole html of learn-more.html
    // how can I get the html of a div in learn-more.html with id="main-images" ???
});
```

EDIT:

The content of learn-more.html:

```
<div id="something" class="hero-unit span-one-third" style="position: relative;">
    Foo Bar
</div>

<div id="main-images" class="hero-unit span-one-third" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="learn-more-photo" class="span-one-third">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/300x180" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="learn-more">
:D
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean print as in, to a printer, or to alert() to the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$response.find('#main-images')` will return an **empty** jQuery object. None of the selected elements has a descendant with ID `main-images`. Instead, one of the selected elements **is** the one you are looking for.

To get the a reference to the `div` use [`.filter()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead :

```
$response.filter('#main-images');
```

If you want to get the HTML, append the content to an empty `div` first and remove the unwanted elements:

```
var container = $('<div />').html(data);
container.children().not('#main-images').remove();
var html = container.html();
```

or use a [`outerHTML` plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html):

```
var html = $response.filter('#main-images').outerHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(data)` returns an array of elements and not an ordinary jQuery object. `$(data)[1]` contains your `#main-images` element.

As Felix Kling answered, you can use `filter` instead of `find`.

```
$(data).filter('#main-images').html();
```