# Find elements inside Data object of jQuery .get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I thought this would be easier to find :)

```
$.get('/page.html', function(data) {
    //get only contents of class="contents"
});
```

I can't seem to find out how to do that.

Comment: can you please elaborate what do you exactly mean by "get only contents of class='contents'"

Comment: Sure. The page in question has a lot of generated code I want to ignore. I only want to get back a specific section of the page I'm loading.

Comment: @dinjas Logging it out just shows me the entire page. How do I convert the returned data into an object that allows me to select a specific element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this...

```
$.get('/page.html', function(data){
   var $page = $(data)
   var $contents = $page.filter('.contents'); /* this will get a reference to the .contents */
   /* do more stuff here 
      ....  
   */
});
```

Have a look at the accepted answer to this SO: [Get HTML of div element returned by .get with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818603/get-html-of-div-element-returned-by-get-with-jquery)

If the structure of the returned content is uncertain (to where sometimes you would need to use `.find()` due to `.contents` being a descendent, you could always perform a check and run `.filter()` or vice versa.

Example:

```
$contents = $page.filter('.contents');
if($contents.length == 0) {
   $contents = $page.find('.contents');
}
```

Just a thought based on the comments posted in other answers.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point, it definitely depends on the structure of the HTML in `data`

Comment: I had `.find` first, but then I came across the other question with a quick Google search.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.find()`:

```
$(data).find(".contents")
```

Here's the final code you could use:

```
$.get('/page.html', function(data) {
    var contents = $(data).find(".contents");
});
```

Then depending on what type of element the `.contents` is, you could use `contents.html()` or `contents.text()` (most elements), or `contents.val()` (input element).

Technically, another idea is to use `.filter()`.

This all depends on the structure of your HTML in `data`. If your structure is like this:

```
<div id="main">
    blah blah
    <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
```

Then the result of `$(data)` will be `[#main]` and you need to use `find`. If your structure is like:

```
<div id="main"><div>
<div class="contents"></div>
<div class="another"></div>
```

Then the result of `$(data)` will be `[#main, .contents, .another]` and you need to use `filter`.

Of course, combining them, it could be:

```
$.get('/page.html', function(data) {
    var all = $(data), contents;
    contents = all.filter(".contents");
    if (!contents.length) {
        contents = all.find(".contents");
    }
    if (contents.length) {
        // It/they was/were found at some point
    }
});
```

Comment: Surprisingly, I did try that. Didn't work. I just get back a jQuery object, but cannot access the .text() or .html()

Comment: @Wesley What is the result of `$(data).find(".contents").length` (like if you `alert` it)

Comment: @Wesley And what is the HTML structure of `data` anyways?

Comment: Length is 0. Based on the fast that fletch's answer works, there seems to be some dependency on casting the object before I run .find() or .filter()?

Comment: @Wesley No, nothing special. Both put `data` in a jQuery object - the "required" part. But it all depends on what your HTML structure that's returned from `/page.html`. Sometimes there's one big element that contains all the elements (and the one you're looking for). Sometimes, there's several elements next to each other (also with elements inside) but one of those are the ones you're looking for. `find` and `filter` do different things. `find` looks at the descendents of the selected elements. `filter` looks at the selected elements

Comment: If you can't be certain of your returned HTML structure, why not add a conditional in there that checks the length following the use of `.find()`...if `0`, then give `.filter()` a shot?

Comment: @fletch Very good point. Hadn't thought of that. Although I'd start with `filter` and then move to `find`. Either way, I added to my answer, so thanks for suggesting that

Comment: Interesting, fun discussion! It seems that the post fletch refers to mentions that starting with .find() always returns an empty jquery object.

Comment: @Wesley Well to me, starting with `filter` makes more sense because it filters/searches the parent elements only, which there should usually be less of, while `find` searches all descendents of all parents, which I would think there would be more of. Anyways, glad you're enjoying the discussion :)

Answer (score 2):

If you create a jQuery object from the returned `data` and the wrapper element in the jQuery set is `.contents` element then `find` fails to find the target element and if the `contents` element is a descendant element then `filter` method fails to select that element. You can create a dummy element, populate it with returned data and use `find` method.

```
$.get('/page.html', function(data) {
    var element = $('<div/>').html(data).find('.contents');
});
```

Comment: This triggers a postback for some unknown reason. Possibly due to something in the results?

Comment: @Wesley What do you get from the request?

Comment: It's a full page, starting from <!DOCTYPE html> all the way to </html>

Comment: Tried to add it, but it's too much.

Comment: @Wesley Okay, note that jQuery removes html, body(_not it's contents_) and head tags if you want to select one of these elements.

Comment: @Wesley What does `$(data).length` `alert`?

Comment: 96, which is much less than the total string length

Comment: @Wesley `.length` doesn't refer to the length of the `data` string. That's what `data.length` would produce - a very large number I'm sure. `$(data).length` refers to how many parent elements were parsed and found. For example, `$("<div></div><span></span>").length` would be 2

Comment: ahhh. I see. Total string length was in the neighborhood of 46000